# What is the best way to represent a large field of objects while using minimal resources?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

all I am looking to develop a project in unity, it is for android! I was wondering if I could get some clarity on a few things. My problem involves me trying to creating a universe of stars, 150,000 individual stars to be exact, granted there would only be a certain percentage in view at any one time. What is the most efficient structure for being able to convince the user of a realistic environment while keeping the overhead to a minimum since it will be on a phone?

What type of objects do I want to use to represent the masses of stars vs. the likes of stars in close proximity that require finer details?

What sort of threading structures should I consider while planning this project?

How easily does a project port from unity to android, in such scenarios?

Any help is much appreciated as I am looking to better develop with unity, cheers

Comment: This question is too broad homie. You've got like 6 questions in there - try and narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not tracking all 150,000 stars, but only the ones that are in view.  When the field of view changes, use a random number generator to define the stars that have just entered it, and drop from memory the ones that have left.  To preserve consistency, you might want to retain the stars for a short period around the current field of view, if the user can do rapid switches in direction.

As for threading, that's less a function of the number of stars you are tracking, and more a function of what it is that you are doing with them - something you didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

1) This question is mainly a game development question and not unity regarding. I just point you in the direction, as a complete answer would be to much. Normally if you need to know where you are in a 3D scene with infinite objects or close (150k is close), you would use a octree for orientation. Constructed like a map, each node of the tree points a direction (West, South, Nord, East, NNW, ...) Then you each of your stars gets 1 node, and you can calculate what is where and how much do you want to see. More information can be found on google. (Quite complicated topic jfyi)

2) Dedicated to 1) with a mix of entity/component design. You will know what I mean after 1) is clear to you.

3) Absolutly Multithreaded Asynchron. 1 Thread Update, 1 Thread Draw, Few Worker Threads (position, ...)

4) The port of Unity Engine is actually working really good. Of course you should have an android peripherial to test and debug on, but most of the time, it will work for you.